# How to remove the character "\" from string on typescript (angular)

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, string, replace

I have a string that is `"\YES\"`

How to simply remove the \ from the string?

```
sessionStorage.getItem('questionList2')!.replace(/"\"/g,'')
```

But all it resulted is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sessionStorage.getItem('questionList2')!.replace(/\\/g,'')
```